# Natural Logarithm Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

For what set of functions is $\int \frac{\ln{f(x)}}{f'(x)}\mathrm{d}x$ defined?

More specifically related to the reason I ask, when 
$$
f(x) = \frac{c}{x} + \arcsin{x} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}
$$
is the integral closed?

Comment: Think you need to tidy up the second equation? Doesn't seem obvious that the integrand is of the form $\frac{\ln f(x)}{f'(x)}$?